# Why might anything https related freezes my computer? How would I go about debugging this?

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, https

I may be wrong, but it appears that any application using https either freezes or gives me an error.

I've tried some obvious stuff (below) but I'm running out of ideas and would really appreciate a pointer as to how I should / could go about debugging this problem.

**Why I Think It's a HTTPS Problem**

Firstly I can't search Google or Yahoo. Loading Chrome and searching from the address/omni bar just gives me the spinning circle and eventually times out (ERR_TIMED_OUT).   Going straight to a http website such as this one works fine. But note how I'm not getting  the gravatar images

[image]

I use a VPN to connect to a web server and manage websites. When I try to open and connect using that, it freezes.

I use Outlook to connect to a number of pop3 accounts. Fine.  When it tries to hook up with Exchange account, Outlook totally freezes.

I can see the home page of my bank's website (http). When I click into online banking (https), Chrome gives me the ERR_TIMED_OUT message

Only the affected application(s) freeze or error out - the rest of the system continues to work fine

**Update**

I restarted Chrome. Now google search works fine. But other https connections don't seem to: 
[image]

I also noticed that when downloading files they reach 100% but never complete properly.

**Debugging Attempts So Far**

Scanning with Malware Bytes, AVG and Super Anti Spyware - they don't find anything wrong.  I'm going to try Eset online scanner as soon as I've posted this.

Disabling AVG

Disabling Firewall

Doing a system restore to a couple of weeks ago, but that doesn't help any.

Looking in the Event Viewer - I didn't see anything obviously wrong here, but I don't have the expertise to look for anything in particular

Comment: Verify you don't have any self-signed certificates installed and/or malware running a proxy on your system.  My suggestion nuke from orbit

Comment: How would I do number 1? I have installed no certs myself. Regarding malware would you recommend using anything specifically, in addition to those I mentioned?

Comment: Research the Superfish problem, other security software, inplements proxies, in order to protect you in theory but they also implemented it wrong